# Forcing training to be done outside of work hours

Tags: united-kingdom, training

I've just been asked to begin a course towards understanding GDPR a little better.

It's fairly indepth, and required for my role (apparently).

I've been asked to sign a document with this clause :-

you are fully committed to studying and completing 
   the course outside of your normal working hours.

There is no mention of remediation or time in lieu for the time worked.

The course has no direct 'personal' benefit which I'd put on my CV etc.

Is this normal? am I right in feeling concerned at this clause?

---

This question does share themes from [How can we motivate employees to complete IT certificates?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/9659/how-can-we-motivate-employees-to-complete-it-certificates) 
but I don't feel the answer given directly answers my question.

---

As an update, I questioned this clause with the operations director, who has stated that in this case, the clause is not needed.

Comment: Were you given any advance warning about this course or possible future training? Maybe it came up in your contract, interview or was informed about it a long time ago.

Comment: Legal questions are expressly off-topic here. My personal opinion is that if it's required for my job, I'll be doing it in the office and on company time. Anything else is working unpaid overtime.

Comment: some training has been discussed, but these requirements have never been tabled. I'm on another course, where I'm off site for a day... I've not been required to sign a form for this one...

Comment: [hardly normal](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/9660/168)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can we motivate employees to complete IT certificates?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/9659/how-can-we-motivate-employees-to-complete-it-certificates)

Comment: @Cronax : Although it shares themes from the other answer, it's a quesiton from the Employee point of view, and also focusing on one specfic aspect :- the requirement to work out of hours. I feel that it's not duplicate due to this.

Comment: The point that is made in the other answer is that it's unacceptable to require employees to improve themselves out of hours without compensation when this improvement is required for the job. This means that the answer to your question is basically the same: you should not accept having to study outside of normal working hours without receiving compensation for it and should probably try to work together with your employer to find a solution that fits.

Comment: Cronax : Fair enough, I'll leave it up to a mod if they want to do anything further with it... I've stated as much on my answer.

Comment: Will they reimburse you for travel, gas, food, and whatnot?

Answer (score 0):

From the comments on the question, and other questions linked it does not seem to be a normal thing to do, to require a employee to dedicate personal time to a business-required training course.